# "Module was not compiled for testing" error when using Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I created a Swift library with `swift package init --type library` and generated an Xcode project with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

Now I'm trying to run the Test scheme in Xcode. It prints following error:

```
Module '<title>' was not compiled for testing
```

However when I run `swift build` and `swift test` in terminal, it works fine.

I have `ENABLE_TESTABILITY` set to `YES` in all of the targets. I didn't change anything in the project except this. How can I make Xcode perform unit testing?

Comment: Seems like Swift-PM 3.1 fixed the issue (and it doesn't generate a separate Test scheme in Xcode project anymore)

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the "Enable Testability" to Yes in build setting over your "Main Target"

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Best thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue today, it seems like `@testable` cannot be used with projects generated by Swift Package Manager.

Removing `@testable` from my import statements solved this issue. Of course, this means we can only test the public interface of our modules.

Comment: Any updates on this? Is it possible to enable testability in a swift package nowadays? Or is the solution still to create a multi Module hierarchy inside a package?

Answer (score -1):

1. Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
2. Select the Info tab.
3. Set the following -
   Build Configuration: Debug
   Add a check mark to Debug executable

Tested with Xcode 12.4(12D4e) and iOS 14.1 deployment target.